# Windows 10, how to switch keyboard layout?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-layout

In Windows 10, when I press `Win + space` (or `alt + shift`) the language switches between Finnish and English, but the keyboard layout stays in Finnish even thought the language is English. How do I configure the English language selection to use English keyboard layout?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change/add keyboard layouts in the Language settings.
Just go to:

**Start --> Settings --> Time & Language --> Region & Language**

Then either:

- Delete the English language then go into Finnish and add the preferred English layout to the already existing Finnish one
- Go into the English tab and add the preferred English layout then delete the Finnish layout from the list

Either way you will be able to switch keyboard layout. In the first case maintaining the Finnish Region and Currency. In the second switching not only layout but Region and Currency as well.